# MVC URL for images downloads the image instead of displaying the view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Newbie to `MVC`. I am trying to display a graph in the browser using `MVC`, but when I run the application the page downloads the image and closes.

**My controller**

```
 public ActionResult DrawChart()
    {
        var chart = new Chart(width: 300, height: 200)
            .AddSeries(
                        chartType: "bar",
                        xValue: new[] { "10 Records", "20 Records", "30 Records", "40 Records" },
                        yValues: new[] { "50", "60", "78", "80" })
                        .GetBytes("png");

        return File(chart, "image/bytes");
    }
```

**My View**

```
    @{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>DrawChart</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <img src="@Url.Action("DrawChart")" alt="Drawing chart with HTML Helper" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a file result with the mime type of `image/bytes` and you also are calling the `GetBytes("png")` method (which I am assuming is getting the PNG Bytes).

In this case you could just try `return File(chart, "image/png");` this should instruct the browser to display the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly write it to the View using Razor as shown below, or use Partial view and render it where ever you want

```
    <div>
@{
    var chart = new Chart(width: 300, height: 200)
                .AddSeries(
                            chartType: "bar",
                            xValue: new[] { "10 Records", "20 Records", "30 Records", "40 Records" },
                            yValues: new[] { "50", "60", "78", "80" })
                            .Write();
    }
</div>
```

Refer this link: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart

Comment: Thank you. The answer and reference were very helpful

Comment: Thank you, Appreciate if you mark it as answer so useful for others